# Beanstalk's nginx not picking the .conf file on my application source bundle

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-code-deploy

I have a Spring Boot application built on Beanstalk (Amazon Linux 2), I need to increase the client_max_body_size because some form data I'm posting contains images and I'm getting the `413: Request Too Large` Nginx error.

I followed [AWS's documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-nginx-configuration/#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20NGINX%20has%20a,in%20the%20NGINX%20configuration%20files.) on how to change this property.

My project structure looks like this now:

[image]

And the content of the file is:

```
client_max_body_size 50M;
```

After deploying I keep getting the same error (with images > 1MB total).

No file has been created in conf.d:

[image]

Is this because how my `buildSpec` packages my application?

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto17
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Nothing to do in the pre_build phase...
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - .platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf
    - target/myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    - appspec.yml
  discard-paths: yes
```

I also tried adding the configuration file into the `artifacts.files` section of my `buildspec.yml`.

I also tried to create the file its content from the `files` section on the buildspec.

I feel like I tried everything, is there anything I may be missing?

**For now, my workaround**

I manually edited the file:

```
cd /etc/nginx/
sudo nano nginx.conf
```

and restarted. That worked, but I want to avoid this manual configuration so it's configured from the application source, as a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on my buildspec.

```
discard-paths: yes
```

was putting all the files on the root path of the bundle. I needed this so I the jar was on the root, but it was putting the `proxy.conf` in the root as well.

Setting that property to no (or removing it) made it work, but I needed a way to change the jar from /target/ to the root so I did it with a post-build command:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto17
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Nothing to do in the pre_build phase...
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip
  post_build:
    commands:
      - mv target/myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar <------ HERE
      - echo Build completed on `date`
artifacts:
  files:
    - .platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf
    - myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    - appspec.yml
```